# Using Django template tag in <img> tag

Tags: html, django

`c_list` includes this:

```
[<Certificate: img/025.jpg>, 
   <Certificate: img/025_fNFY8ur.jpg>, <Certificate: img/024.jpg>]
```

I'm using it like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for cer in c_list %}
      <li><img src="{% static '{{ cer }}' %}"/></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But it returns this and no pictures is showing:

```
<img src="/static/%7B%7B%20cer%20%7D%7D">
```

How should I use it?

Comment: It doesn't work because it's outputting {{cert}} surrounded by escaped { and } characters, so it's not evaluating your **cer** variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<ul>
    {% for cer in c_list %}
      <li><img src="{% static cer %}"/></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need also `.url` from `Certificate`'s Image field:

```
<ul>
{% for cer in c_list %}
  <li><img src="{% static cer.image.url %}"/></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

if the image field is called `image`