# Using AngularJS template tag inside Django {% %} tag

Tags: python, html, django, angularjs

I've changed my `AngularJS` template tags to `{$ $}` and I have this code in my Django powered webpage:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="image in pictures[currentCat]">
    <a>
        <img src="{% static '{$ image.imgs $}' %}" />
    </a>
</li>
```

Now as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710983/using-django-template-tag-in-img-tag?answertab=votes#tab-top) in my other question, I tried this solution:

```
<img src="{% static image.imgs %}" />
```

But then `image.imgs` is not a django variable so there's no picture.

I also tried this workaround:

```
<img src="src="static/{$ image.imgs $}" />
```

It works but only if `DEBUG=TRUE`. When I changed it to `False`, problem is still there.
How can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

The html rendered code for image `src` is:

```
src="/static/%7B%24%20image.imgs%20%24%7D"
```

Comment: So image.imgs is actually meant to be rendered with Angular?

Comment: What about the rendered html? Is it blank, or some invalid value ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use angular variables in place of Django variables, they are rendered at completely different times. Django renders the template and its variables on the server before it is sent to the client. Angular variables are rendered in the client browser, after the response has been received from the server.

Comment: @FrEaKmAn Yes. it has a value like 'img/image.jpg'

Comment: @karthikr I updated the answer with the rendered html

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony So any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this trick as a workaround and it works perfect no matter whether `DEBUG=True or False`:

```
<img src="{% static a %}{$ image.imgs $}" />
```